# Slick JS vertical with two elements in same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I've a problem with Slick. I need to display two elements in a same line with a vertically animation. It's working fine with the horizontally display.

```
$(".slide").slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  autoplay: false,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  vertical: true
});
```

My complete code : https://jsfiddle.net/pzvov8og/

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you !

Comment: Use the `vertical: true` setting but restructure the HTML to put two of the elements inside one `slide` so that slick sees them as one?

Comment: Yes, but the HTML code is generated dynamically, I do not know how many ads there will be.

Comment: Oh. Do you have control of the code which generates them? Perhaps some changes to that will work?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write: slidesToScroll: 2, because you want display two elements

```
$(".slide").slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  autoplay: false,
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  vertical: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set infinite: false, you set slides to show: 2 , and its trying to show 4 slide for infinite scroll

Comment: would u mind formatting your answer a bit

Comment: when you set config infinite: true and slidesToShow: 2, slick tries to clone elements for infinite scrolling. And there is problem in slick css with clonned elements, if you will set infinite: false; everything will work fine (it worked for me)